# How would one cite images from Logos Bible Software?

Tags: citation-style, software

I have done a word study using Logos Bible Software. I have images of how much the word 'agape' in Greek is used in the LXX and NT. How would I cite these images in Chicago Manual of Style?

Comment: Are these images generated by you using this software, or are you copying existing images from a published work?

Comment: These are images created by myself using the software data.

Comment: What's the LXX and NT?

Comment: LXX= Greek Old Testament and NT = New Testament

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## You don't.

You don't cite them, since they're not a part of another published work. They're a part of the current published work that you're producing. The software is just a tool you're using to produce a part of the paper, so you don't need to cite it any more than you'd cite Microsoft Word for being the text editor you used to draft it in.

Maybe you could reference the use of the software in your methodology section, but you'd simply cite whatever paper first introduced the software, if any such papers existed, using the standard format for citing other papers.